# Why is there a let in OCaml's List.map?

Tags: syntax, functional-programming, ocaml

In OCaml 3.12.1, `List.map` is written as follows:

```
let rec map f = function
    [] -> []
  | a::l -> let r = f a in r :: map f l
```

I'd expect that last line to be written as `| a::l -> f a :: map f l`, but instead, there is a seemingly useless `let` binding. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe it is there to guarantee an order of function application for the map. The order of evaluation of simple expressions in OCaml is unspecified, so without the `let` the order of applications of `f` to the elements of the list would be unspecified. Since OCaml is not a pure language, you really would like the order to be specified (`f` is called on the head of the list first, and so on recursively).

Comment: Indeed, every version of OCaml I tried (up to 4.00.1) showed the following behaviour: Define `map` by `let rec map f = function [] -> [] | x::xs -> f x :: map f xs;;` and then call `map print_string ["a"; "b"; "c"];;`. This prints the list-elements from right to left.

Comment: Why it is needed to specify the order here in List.map? I think `f a` being evaluated before or after doesn't matter here, right?

Comment: As long as `f` is a pure function, no, order of evaluation doesn't matter. But can we guarantee it always will be a pure function?